# What data structure to use for implementing a library management system

Tags: clojure

I'm new to functional programming and am currently at the end of "Getting Clojure" book.  Since most of the examples in the book refer to books/library management, i thought of implementing a library management system as a project to help me learn and clear the concepts.  I would like some advise on what would be the best data structure to hold the library - I'm thinking of either a vector of book maps or a map of book maps.  Maps are easy to lookup.  Vectors can be accessed quickly as well.  I'm thinking of

```
{:ISBN {:title "Book title" :edition 1 :publisher "ABC publishing"}}
```

this way the lookup will be on ISBN number, but i would also like to lookup using book title ..but not sure how.  Any help, suggestions, advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to be more specific in your question.  Also, look up examples for the function `filter`.

Comment: Hi Alan, I apologise for not being clear.  I want to store books in a data structure ..e.g. a map containing books and each map key is a ISBN number for lookup.  But this has a disadvantage that I can't lookup using book title.  If i'm not mistaken, filter would have to run through all the list of books, but I'm interested in something which can do a quick lookup using book title.

Comment: You are starting to describe a database with multiple indexes.  Just write it as you described, then write functions `get-by-isbn` and `get-by-title`.  Write one of them (probably title since it's not unique) using `filter`.  Do some timings for 100, 10k, and 10M books if you want.  You may be surprised how fast `filter` can be.

Comment: Hi Alan, Thank you.  I will do as you suggested. I just don't want to use a database just yet :)

Comment: The ISBN is a number, unique for each book. Either you have a map with keys :ISBN, :title and so on for each book which you put then into a map or a list. Alternatively, you don't use :ISBN as a key, but each ISBN _number_ (actually a string) as a key in a map containing all books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `index` function in `clojure.set`:

```clj
(require '[clojure.set :as set])

(def library #{{:title "Book title" :edition 1 :publisher "ABC publishing" :isbn "1234"}
               {:title "A title" :edition 2 :publisher "123 publishing" :isbn "4321"}})

(def by-isbn (set/index library [:isbn]))

(by-isbn {:isbn "1234"})
;; => #{{:title "Book title", :edition 1, :publisher "ABC publishing", :isbn "1234"}}

(def by-title (set/index library [:title]))

(by-title {:title "A title"})
;; => #{{:title "A title", :edition 2, :publisher "123 publishing", :isbn "4321"}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Will try your approach

Answer (score 0):

In java you can use a data structure called Trie. it is better than Hashmaps and the time complexity of operations are O(1).
In this DS we can reuse the words like if we already have the word 'new' and you want to add another word 'news' It will it will just use the existing word new to make a new word. which stores storage.

Comment: Answer is unclear. Please check the English and try adding supporting information.